# How to make this completly flat?

Tags: modeling

how I can make this flat? I want one flat surface at the bottom of this car. Any help? Thanks[image: i want this face flat]

Comment: Select all that bottom vertices and use Alt+s, z, 0(zero).

Comment: Don't hit Alt, just s, z, 0.

Comment: Oops! My bad. Thank you, FFeller.